# Advantage to using describe/it over feature/scenario in specs? (besides syntactic sugar)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, testng, acceptance-testing

**Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.1.10, RSpec 2.13.0, Capybara 2.2.1**

I am writing tests for a Rails 3 app -- a GUI for customers (and admins) to configure various phone settings. I have written 6 or so spec files, with plenty others wrriten before (to which I used as templates). The following is a snapshot of what the spec files look like.

```
# spec/features/admin/administrators_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
include AdministratorHelper
include Helpers
feature "Exercise Administrators page"
  include_context "shared admin context"
  background do
    visit administrators_path
  end
  scenario "show index page" do
    title.should == "Administrators"
  end
  # ... other happy path tests
  # SAD PATH TESTS #
  scenario "validation: delete no administrators", js:true do
    click_button "Delete"
    page.driver.accept_js_confirms!
    error_message("Error: You did not select any administrators for deletion.")
  end
end
```

To my understanding, `feature`/`scenario` are exclusive to Capybara... and acceptance testing. Other collaborators said that our "acceptance tests" test everything -- whether the database saved entries, whether the view is rendered correctly, etc. Each spec is associated with a page in the GUI, not by model/controller.

He had me take a course on edX (CS169.1x), and they taught testing differently -- separate spec file per model and controller. They also used the `describe`/`context`/`it` method of writing tests.

1. Is there any advantage to writing tests with `describe`/`it` over `feature`/`scenario`? (Besides syntactic sugar)
2. By using Capybara's `feature`/`scenario`, does it slow down the test suite? (Compared to using RSpec's keywords)
3. What exactly are the tests I am writing (as explained in the code block)? Acceptance, unit, a combination?
4. Would writing tests like the above *alone* achieve higher coverage? (Our next goal is >80%)

Thank you for all the help and clarification.

Comment: This is a well-thought out question, but it is a bit broad and subject to opinion too. Definitions of test types are a bit blurry around the edges.

Comment: I tried to rephrase my question. I hope it is less subjective. My reasoning is that maybe since Capybara is a library on top of RSpec, it would take longer to process. (Not sure how much longer... We are currently at 535 examples at 15 minutes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question is a bit broad, but it is possible to answer with some advice and opinions based on my own experience.

> 1. Is there any advantage to writing tests with describe/it over feature/scenario? (Besides syntactic sugar)

Not as far as I know. However, you may find some convenient test framework features are easier to implement in one scheme than another.

> 2. By using Capybara's feature/scenario, does it slow down the test suite? (Compared to using RSpec's keywords)

Just using the keywords will not be a large factor in speed of processing. What kind of web driver and host simulation you are using will have a larger impact.

> 3. What exactly are the tests I am writing (as explained in the code block)? Acceptance, unit, a combination?

I would call them acceptance tests. However, there is not always a clear dividing line, and you need to look at how the tests will be run, and how they will be used in your development process.

A mature development pipeline may have two or three separate test suites used for different purposes, and probably implemented using different test frameworks. You might want a set of very fast tests (usually unit tests) implemented to run as a quick automated test of new code commits for instance.

> 4. Would writing tests like the above alone achieve higher coverage? (Our next goal is >80%)

The tests can exercise any user-accessible feature of the application, and any of your own code that is exercised can be considered covered. It is likely you can get higher than 80% C0 coverage (Ruby coverage tools don't usually provide deeper details such as C1), provided you do not have a lot of utility scripts or other code that is not user-accessible.

---

I suspect using a specific test framework's keywords will have minimal impact. However, using Capybara to acceptance test the application via the web interface is going to be much slower than running lower-level unit tests of individual modules.

Speed of tests can vary orders of magnitude. For tight unit tests around a fast module, I might expect to run 100 examples per second. On a web development project, I typically run 10-20 examples per second on unit tests, but maybe 1 example per second on acceptance tests (which is roughly the ballpark you are getting here). When using Capybara via a browser driver on a hosted copy of a site, I might expect to run one example in 10 seconds, so a suite with over 100 tests has to be run only for critical-path tests, such as versus release candidates.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was much more in-depth than I was expecting. I have only been working around Rails for 3 months now, so some concepts are still new to me. I trust the other collaborators in that we do test all aspects of the app... My main reason to ask was because during research on WebMock, any and all RSpec tests followed describe/it which led me to think there was a larger difference... Thank you again